# Ignore change for data source in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I use terraform to provision an RDS database. After the database is created, I use local-exec block to overwrite its master-password inside the database itself, as in the secret store.

My problem is now, that when I run Terraform for the next time the change in the secret store is detected and the password is fetched and updated. This way, the password again is stored in the terraform state - A thing I wanted to avoid in the first place.

My code looks like the following and already has an`ignore_changes` for the version, but the data source does not support it. Is there any way to ignore a change there as well?

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
  secret_string = data.aws_secretsmanager_random_password.password.random_password
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [secret_string, secret_binary]
  }
 }
    
 data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
   secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
   depends_on = [
     aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret,
     aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_version
   ]
 }
    
 resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
   identifier                 = var.name
   password                   = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_version.secret_string)["password"]
   ...
}
```

Related questions:

- [How to tell Terraform to skip the secret manager resource if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670949/how-to-tell-terraform-to-skip-the-secret-manager-resource-if-it-exists)

Comment: Why do you have both a resource and a data source for the same `secret_version`? If you just referenced the `resource` directly and completely deleted the redundant data source, then this would work exactly like you want, since the `resource` is configured to properly ignore changes to the secret value.

Comment: As far as I know, both secret and secret_version have no attribute to retrieve the secret directly. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. the `secret_version` resource has the same read attributes as the `secret_version` data source. Please refer to the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret_version Any time you have both a resource and a data source that reference the same thing in Terraform, you are implementing an anti-pattern and you should check the documentation to see how to use the `resource` directly.

Comment: @MarkB this was it! "[..]in addition to the arguments above" I missed this phrase. That's the answer I searched for. Do you want to make it a proper answer, so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `data` source from your code and just reference the secret value from the `resource`. The `resource` already ignores changes to the secret value, so it will work just like you want.

You should never have both a `data` source and a `resource` in your Terraform code that references the same thing, since all the values available on the `data` source are also available on the `resource`. This is an anti-pattern, and if you tried to apply that infrastructure to a brand-new, empty AWS account you would actually get an error, because Terraform will always try to look up the `data` source during the `plan` phase, before it creates any resources.